# Drupal sorts its content by one field at a time, cannot we customize this sort first by type and then by title in content administration panel?

Tags: administration

Drupal sorts its content by one field at a time, cannot we customize this sort first by type and then by title in content administration panel ? Please share if there is any solutin for that.

Answer (score 0):

In the content administration section of the admin (/admin/content), you select the type as you normally would to filter a particular content type.

From there, to sort content by title of that type click on the top of the table on the title field. Your URL should look like this(/admin/content?sort=asc&order=Title).

That way, your content is sorted by both type and title.

Possible sorting sorting options are Title, Author (alphabetical order), Status (published/not published), Updated date.

Comment: Thanks @inkovic, it really works. But there are some limitations.